# why my server terminal doesnt show error?

Tags: python, django, apache2, python-imaging-library, mod-wsgi

I am connected to my VPS (Ubuntu) via SSH.
I use Django, where I process 1000's of images via Django-imagekit ( PIL ). but for some reason, it is not generating an error it just stops/terminates there. it shows all other print commands and everything.

yes, I tried 'try and except' but it doesn't work, it just terminates at 'try' only.

**CODE:**

```
from imagekit import ImageSpec
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFit

class Thumbnail(ImageSpec):
        processors = [ResizeToFit(1200)]
        format = 'WEBP'
        options = {'quality': 90}

Main_image = open('path/to/image.jpg','rb')
Preview_gen = Thumbnail(source=Main_image)
Preview = Preview_gen.generate()
```

**Error while executing the last line**

( but works fine on my local machine )

Specs:

- Ubuntu Linux 18.04.2
- Python==3.6.9
- Django==3.0.7
- Pillow==8.2.0
- psycopg2==2.8.6
- psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
- django-imagekit==4.0.2

anyone any idea?

*error causing image [Wallpaper, .jpg, 9600 x 5598](https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/z8/wallhaven-z8m3yg.jpg)*

this is the problem for very few images

Comment: Your question lacks a [mre]. How would people know what exactly your problem is if you don't share the relevant details. For instance why is there supposed to be an error? What code is it on which your process stops executing?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat sorry my bad, please check now. and i think the error might be ...` truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process` as when I manually try uploading the same image to server for processing via views.py, this is the error in the apache error log

Comment: show the error plz...

Comment: @newlife that's what I raised the issue for...

Comment: if you don't get error than maybe you should remove `try/except`  because maybe they hide error  - especially when someone use `except Exception: pass`. You could also write information to log file - to see which lines work and which don't.

Comment: if you have problem with few images then you could try to compate them to see if they have something similar - i.e size, method of compression, incorrect extension, color pallete (8-bit, 24-bit, 32-bit, transparency), etc.

Comment: @furas i have compared dimensions and extensions, no problem. how do I check method of compression?

Comment: you can get few information with standard linux command `file` - `file Wallpaper.jpg`. But you could use image viewer to get some data - or you could use `pillow` for this [Get the Basic image information with Pillow](https://www.codespeedy.com/get-the-basic-image-information-with-pillow-python/), Maybe you could get some information from [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) but it is rather for audio and video.

Comment: `ImageMagic` gives also many information [Image Format and Characteristics](https://imagemagick.org/script/identify.php). It is used by python module [Wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.6/) for processing images - but maybe it can get also these information and then you can write script for comparing images.